# What is "HAL remoting" in Android?

Tags: android, android-source, hal, hidl

In Android HIDL description at [hidl-cpp](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl-cpp/interfaces) something called "HAL remoting" is mentioned. Is it part of existing Android? Named differently?

Comment: To avoid copy-paste from general HIDL documentation. Question is - is "HAL remoting" possible and where it is documented?

Answer (score 1):

**The Good**: HAL remoting is possible.

**The Bad**: HAL remoting is not documented.

**The Ugly**: Due to Binders multi-threaded synchronous communication it is quite hard to do HAL remoting. Especially if you want to achieve it with a single-threaded event-loop and a synchronous TCP socket.

Answer (score 0):

HAL is Hardware Abstraction Layer, that links the higher level routines to the bare-metal code. Remote HAL is when the HAL of another device or of another hardware is used, meaning you use the higher level routines that are implemented by HAL on a remote device